# Fckeditor to ckeditor4

Tags: ckeditor4.x

**Issue:**

Starting off my issue is that my content does not appear for me to edit.

- I can see it on my front end, but not the backend.
- Likely due to the old fckedit program.
- Im trying to figure out the next step to replace the old FCKeditor within my page with ckeditor4.
- My site was custom built from scratch (I didn't build it). I have the ckeditor4 loaded in my include folder and I was able to test it using my URL.

However, I can't get it to work on the page or show my content that is not reachable on the backend.

**Here is my page coding:**

```
{include file='siteadmin/header.tpl'}

{include file='siteadmin/left.tpl'}
<h1>{if $action eq 'add'}Add{else}Edit{/if} Page</h1>
<form method="post" action="{$_conf_vars.ADMIN_URL}index.php?opt={$opt}&a={$action}{$qstr}" name="frm" id="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {if $show_msg ne ''}

  {$show_msg}

  {/if}
  <input type="hidden" name="page_id" id="page_id" value="{$page_id}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="alias_id" id="alias_id" value="{$alias_id}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="page_title" id="page_title" value="{$page_title|@StripSlash}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="adapters" id="adapters" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="btn" value="{$action}" />
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="listdata">
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Page Title:<span class="star">*</span></div></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="page_title" name="page_title" value="{$page_title|@StripSlash}" maxlength="300" style="width:532px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Page Alias:<span class="star">*</span></div></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="page_alias" maxlength="100" id="page_alias" value="{$page_alias|@StripSlash}" size="60" />
        <em>(a-z, 0-9, hyphen (-) only)</em></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>


      <td valign="top"><div align="right">Description:<span class="star">*</span></div></td>
   <td>
 {php}
        $sBasePath = $_conf_vars['ROOT_URL'].'include/fckeditor/';
        $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('page_body') ;
        $oFCKeditor->BasePath = $sBasePath ;
        $oFCKeditor->ToolbarSet ="Default";
        $oFCKeditor->Value = StripSlash($this->get_template_vars('page_body')) ;
        $oFCKeditor->Height = 500;
        $oFCKeditor->Width = 700;
        $oFCKeditor->Create() ;
       {/php}       

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td width="31%"><div align="right">Meta Title:</div></td>
      <td width="69%"><textarea name="meta_title" id="meta_title"  rows="4" cols="100">{$meta_title|@StripSlash}</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Meta Keywords:</div></td>
      <td><textarea name="meta_keywords" id="meta_keywords" rows="4" cols="100">{$meta_keywords|@StripSlash}</textarea>
      <br/><small> <small>Separated by commas</small></small></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Meta Description:</div></td>
      <td><textarea name="meta_desc" id="meta_desc" rows="4" cols="100">{$meta_desc|@StripSlash}</textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="270">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="689" align="right"> {if $action eq "add" or $action eq "more"}
        <button type="submit" onclick="document.frm.btn.value = 'success';">Add and Go To Listing</button>
        <button type="submit" onclick="document.frm.btn.value = 'more';">Add More</button>
        {else}
        <button type="submit" onclick="document.frm.btn.value = 'update';">Update and Go To Listing</button>
        {/if}
        <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='index.php?opt={$opt}{$qstr}'">Cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
{include file='siteadmin/footer.tpl'}
```

Thank you,
leon